# Github repository statistics

Tags: github, statistics

Is there a tool available which generates some statistics about a github repository? With statistics I mean analyzing commits and issues which are related to the code.

Statistics for example:

- which file has the most changes (commits)
- which file is most related with bugs (with a specific label)
- ...

Comment: What do you mean by "which file has the most changes"?  Do you mean on a per-commit basis?  Also GitHub doesn't compile code or catch errors in source code...

Comment: GitHub generates difs for you.  I don't know if a tool which can gauge the amount of changes though.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some statistics under the **Pulse** and [**Graphs**](https://help.github.com/articles/about-repository-graphs/#) tabs in a GitHub repository. The **Graphs** tab includes a Commits chart. Anyone with push access to a repository can [view its traffic](https://help.github.com/articles/accessing-basic-repository-data/#viewing-traffic-to-a-repository), including full clones (not fetches), visitors from the past 14 days, referring sites, and popular content in the Traffic graph.

If you wanted to drill down into commit volume on particular file you can use the [commits](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository) API endpoint. Here is an example call:

`curl -u <USER>:<API_KEY> https://api.github.com/repos/<OWNET>/<REPO>/commits`

You have the option to pass in a `path` and `since`/`until` dates to narrow your results.

Answer (score 0):

The [herdstat tool](https://github.com/herdstat) can be used to generate *contribution graphs* known from GitHub user profiles but for individual repositories or aggregated ones for multiple repositories, e.g., all repositories in a GitHub organization.

The tool is packaged as a Docker image and can be used as follows:

```
docker run --name herdstat-dev -it herdstat/herdstat:v0.4.0 \ 
    /herdstat -r herdstat contribution-graph -u 2022-12-31
docker cp $(docker ps -aqf "name=herdstat-dev"):/contribution-graph.svg .
```

The graph is generated for a 52 week time frame ending with the date specified via the `-u` / `--until` flag. The repositories to be analyzed are given using the `-r` / `--repositories` flag. It can be set either to owners like `herdstat` or repositories like `hertstat/herdstat`. In the first case all *public* repositories owned by `herdstat` are analyzed.

Depending on your use case, you can use the [herdstat GitHub action](https://github.com/herdstat/herdstat-action) to perform the analysis in an automated fashion, e.g., nightly or as part of your CI/CD pipeline and embed the resulting graph into your README file using an HTML image tag.

The tool is still in its early stages, but it generates informative and nice looking contribution charts like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJSO4.png).

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of herdstat.